# Cannot rename column that does not exist in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I'm fairly new to R and am working on a school assignment. I have had to read in an Excel file and rename several columns. I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

UN_migrant <- read_excel("UN_migrant.xlsx", 
    sheet = "Table 6", skip = 15)

UN_migrant <- UN_migrant %>%
  rename(
    Country = `..2`,
    Country_Code = `..4`,
    Type = `..5`,
    "1990" = "1990...6",
    "1995" = "1995...7",
    "2000" = "2000...8",
    "2005" = "2005...9",
    "2010" = "2010...10",
    "2015" = "2015...11"
  )

Migration <- select(UN_migrant, Country, Country_Code, Type,
                    "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", "2010", "2015")

head(Migration)
```

When I run the code, it makes it to rename but I get the following error:

```
"Error: Can't rename columns that don't exist. x The column `..2` doesn't exist."
```

I've done some searching and tried double quotes around ...2, 4 and 5 but I still receive the same error. I also tried calling rename specifically from dplyr using `dplyr::rename()` and I still got the same error message.

These are the column names in the data frame

```
colnames(UN_migrant)
 [1] "...1"      "...2"      "...3"      "...4"      "...5"      "1990...6"  "1995...7" 
 [8] "2000...8"  "2005...9"  "2010...10" "2015...11" "1990...12" "1995...13" "2000...14"
[15] "2005...15" "2010...16" "2015...17" "1990-1995" "1995-2000" "2000-2005" "2005-2010"
[22] "2010-2015"
```

Can someone explain why I am receiving this error and share some documentation.

Comment: Can you shoow the column names of `UN_migrant`

Comment: Your column name has 3 dots `"...2"`

Comment: I figured out that I was missing a '.' on the first three column names. I just had to add it  to the rename function. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

We can make the code shorter with `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
 UN_migrant %>%
      rename(
          Country = `...2`,
          Country_Code = `...4`,
          Type = `...5`) %>%         
       rename_at(vars(contains('..')), ~ str_remove(.,  "\\.\\..*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is because you must modify the syntax this form: dplyr::rename(...... etc)